# Why have gas prices gone up so much recently?

Tags: inflation, price, covid-19-crisis, oil, russia

Gas prices are soaring. Russia cant have this much influence on the world economy, or can it? Maybe it is due to a post COVID recession?

Comment: Gasoline or natural gas?